# Shell&ServicesEngine 3.0.3 Malware

Tags: windows, malware

For a while now, I have this weird malware program on my computer which keeps reinstalling itself every once in awhile. It shows up in the installed programs list as `Shell&ServicesEngine 3.0.3`. It causes various problems on my computer such as hiding the buttons bar on StackExchange sites, blocking some applications from accessing the Internet and it also sometimes closes my Google Chrome. The later it might try to steal my passwords since it's required to close the browser before reading the passwords file. [Due to Google's weak security, it's possible to retrieve the passwords programmatically on the same machine](http://blog.elliottkember.com/chromes-insane-password-security-strategy).

It can be uninstalled manually but surprise, it doesn't stay that way and keeps coming back. I already installed [AVAST!](https://www.avast.com/index), [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/avira-free-antivirus) and ran [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) but they didn't succeed in removing or detecting the malware. On the Internet I also didn't find anything useful regarding this junk application. What should I try to get rid of it? Just the weird problems and this weird application visible under `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` are a clear indication that something isn't right.

I think I figured out the location of the application:
`C:\Windows\Shell&ServicesEngine_09122015182218`

Also its task name is `NetworkAnalyserService`. It also ran another process called `Netman`. After terminating both, the issues causes are temporarily gone (the buttons bar for example loads again).

Comment: your Chrome password link is 2 years old and the problem was remedied

Comment: Unfortunately, we aren't tech support or a virus removal forum. I'm not sure who to direct you to.

Comment: Are you sure that there is malware? This could al be explained by a faulty network driver.

Comment: @schroeder:
It comes with an uninstaller but odd enough but when I do uninstall it, it comes back later and only causes problems. This behavior is very virus-like. Serious programs shouldn't resist from being uninstalled. The Chrome issue still exists, external applications can view the passwords in Chrome. Check out ChromePass to see what I mean.

Comment: The problem described in the link is no longer relevant, I did not say that there were no issues. Regardless, this is not the right forum for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get rid of this malware by using [`RegScanner`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) and deleting ALL registry keys containing the String `Shell&ServicesEngine` as well as uninstalling the program and deleting the [`Windows Service`](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/) entries for it. Finally rebooted the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps in (great!) BullyWiiPlaza's answer, I also had to do this:

- Delete `WinServicejp.exe` file and its whole directory C:\Windows\SysWOW64\updtSer (contains also WinServicejp.exe.config file)

*Long story:*

As it turned out, I got infected from software called JpgToPdf. I realized that from examining the process `Shell&ServicesEngine` (and others mentioned in OP). But killing these processes, deleting executables and clearing registry did not help. After restart, Shell&ServicesEngine 3.0.3 was back.

Then, using [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx), I noticed some packets being send from WinServejp.exe. In the same directory there was WinServejp.exe.config file in which I found URL to www.hahomedia.com/soft/txt/jpgtopdf.txt - this text file spoiled itself with strings 'Shell&ServicesEngine' and 'JpgToPdfSetup' together.

So I decided it is safe to declare WinServicejp.exe malware (undetected in Kaspersky, ESET, some anti-malwares and non-existent in internet search so far) and deleted it. I did not encounter any problems nor suspitious behaviour on my Windows machine since then.

Comment: I also found another approach that worked which was running SpyHunter and letting it remove everything it found. It's not a free application though but it worked for removing `Shell&ServicesEngine` permanently

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i encountered the same problem, and i got it fixed like this,

[Don't run the default uninstall option provideded in the `Shell&ServicesEngine_*` package, it wont work]

open a command prompt with admin rights, run the following commands one by one.
(not sure if the service names will be same for you, but im sure it will be of the`Shell&ServicesEngine*` pattern. you can confirm the services names in "services" hit `win+r` and execute `services.msc` command)

```
sc stop "Shell&ServicesEngine14012016000932"
sc delete "Shell&ServicesEngine14012016000932"
sc stop "Shell&ServicesEngine14012016000932_updater_service"
sc delete "Shell&ServicesEngine14012016000932_updater_service"
```

and then delete the `Shell&ServicesEngine_*` folder under `C:\Windows\`

`Shell&ServicesEngine 3.0.3` will still be listed in the installed programs list, because the registry entries are still there.

Use [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) to find and delete entries with the String `Shell&ServicesEngine` (dont do this step without deleting the `Shell&ServicesEngine_*` folder under `C:\Windows\`)

Do an `sfc /SCANNOW` on an admin level command prompt after doing all the above (will take a few minutes to finish). and restart windows.

I hope this helped.