# Blocking executable with variable file name from running

Tags: windows, windows-registry, process, blocking

[I have some annoying malware/unwanted program](https://superuser.com/questions/1011641/shellservicesengine-3-0-3-malware) on my PC and can't get rid of it so I thought of blocking its executable(s) from running. For the latter, I found [How to Block an Application or .EXE from Running in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/180803/how-to-block-an-application-or-.exe-from-running-in-windows/) on How-To Geek; this describes how to create a blacklist of executables that will not be allowed to run. Unfortunately, the program's executable name contains a random number/date, meaning that it cannot be referred to using a static name such as `Notepad.exe` since it changes every time. I thought of writing some kind of regular expression matching all executables that start with `Shell&ServicesEngine` and end with `.exe` for the blocking. How do you do it though? <del>Note that I appreciate as well if you know how to **properly** solve this malware problem.</del>

Comment: Are there any `.EXE` files in `C:\Windows\Shell&ServicesEngine_09122015182218`?  (Have you tried blocking those names?)  Have you tried blocking `Netman` and `NetworkAnalserService`?

Comment: Yes, there are `.exe` files in the folder but they are named after the parent folder name mostly. `NetworkAnalserService` actually is one of them so it has a variable name

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for other malware. It's hardly ever just one. Or if the processes don't try to start up again after being terminated add a strings with any name to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` with the values `"taskkill /f /im /t netman.exe"` and `"taskkill /f /im /t Shell&ServicesEngine*"` so they get killed at startup.

Comment: They only start up once in awhile and not necessarily at boot. That makes it so hard to figure out what's going on. Your solution would be ideal if it kept executing the `taskkill` command in the background. However, I can do this myself now. Thanks